# Convert a list with mixed data types into a string without removing quotes from string elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list like this

```
[99999, 'Hi', '2019-02-26 07:20:14', 'this', 'that']
```

I want to convert it into a string like this

```
"(99999, 'Hi', '2019-02-26 07:20:14', 'this', 'that')"
```

I tried this to get a comma separated string but it removes the single quotes from the string elements

```
",".join([str(x) for x in mylist])
Out[46]: '99999,Hi,2019-02-26 07:20:14,this,that'
```

How can I convert a mixed data type list to string while retaining the quotes if the element is a string type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you `repr()` and`tuple()` to do that:

```
a = [99999, 'Hi', '2019-02-26 07:20:14', 'this', 'that']

print(repr(tuple(a)))
```

#### Results:

```
(99999, 'Hi', '2019-02-26 07:20:14', 'this', 'that')
```